# Find scalars to show a norm inequality.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I've been trying to figure out book problem while studying for an exam, and nothing I've tried has worked. Here's the statement:

> For any $x,y\in H$, find scalars $|\lambda|=1=|\mu|$ such that $$ \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2\leq \|\lambda x+\mu y\|^2 $$

Here $H$ is a Hilbert space. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you even try expanding the RHS first?

Comment: Yes, I've gotten to $\|\lambda x+\mu y\|^2=\|x\|^2 + 2 Re\langle \lambda x,\mu y\rangle +\|y\|^2$, but I can't find $\lambda,\mu$ to make $2 Re\langle \lambda x,\mu y\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x,y\in H$.

Comment: No, no, I guess, it's not about the same $\lambda,\mu$ for all $x,y$: these scalars may depend on $x,y$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

1. We can assume $\lambda=1$, as $\|\lambda x+\mu y\|=|\lambda|\cdot\|x+\frac\mu\lambda y\| = \|x+\mu\bar\lambda y\| $.
2. $\|x+\alpha y\|^2=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+\langle x,\alpha y\rangle+\langle \alpha y,x\rangle$ if $|\alpha|=1$.
3. We consider $x$ and $y$ fixed, and look for ($\lambda$ and) $\mu$ for these fixed vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Using the identity $\|z\|^2 = \langle z,z\rangle$ we get

$$\|\lambda x + \mu y \|^2 = \langle \lambda x + \mu y,\lambda x + \mu y\rangle =|\lambda|^2 \|x\|^2+ \lambda \overline \mu \langle x,y\rangle + \overline \lambda \mu \langle y,x\rangle + |\mu|^2 \|y\|^2.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: After some calculations it is obtained that from the inequality indicated in the statement $0\leq \lambda \overline{\mu}\langle x,y\rangle+\overline{\lambda}\mu \langle y,x\rangle$